# Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_headerLayout' in package

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm going to create expandable layout content so I use this https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout 
 I got error that says no resource identifier found:

```
>         Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_headerLayout' in package 'com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp'
>     Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_contentLayout' in package
> 'com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp'
>     Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_headerLayout' in package 'com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp'
>     Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_contentLayout' in package
> 'com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp'
```

it can't find my view_header and view_content xml file in my layout folder
here are  my xml code:

activity main.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
            expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
            android:background="#e74c3c"/>

        <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

view content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Hello World !"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#c0392b"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click ME !"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="ExpandableLayout Header!"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
        expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
        android:background="#e74c3c"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're pointing to the wrong package. `com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp` vs `com.andexert.expandablelayout.library`

Comment: I did it before but doesn't solved <com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp.ExpandableLayoutListView

Comment: you know I got this package by android studio IDE default autocomplete code

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

With:

```
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.andexert.expandablelayout.library"
```

This is of course assuming the library containing the custom view has been added to your project in your `build.gradle`

Comment: then I don't need to change com.andexert.expandablelayout.library in xml code to <com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp.ExpandableLayoutListView

Comment: I got another error: nable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp/com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.example.android.collapsedcontentapp.ExpandableLayout